# Is there an HTML5 validator plugin for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, html5

Is there a plugin for Firefox to validate HTML 5?

I've always used [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249), but if my webpage has a `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` doctype it complains about it not having a doctype at all.

I specifically would like one similar to the one I linked, where the verification happens *on your computer* and instantaneous and automatic, without needing to send any data to a third-party server and then wait for a reply.

Comment: Possible same on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918419/firefox-addon-or-other-tool-to-locally-validate-html-pages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the best one I found so far:

> https://github.com/rogerjohansson/html5validator (see Downloads for an xpi)

You should not use the `validator.nu` online service with it, since it causes a [DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack on the online service, and you will probably be banned from using the service as a countermeasure (see https://github.com/rogerjohansson/html5validator/issues/6). The cool thing is, it does not send the URL to the validator, but the HTML data directly; this means that local sites or password-protected sites can also be checked.

Validation can be turned on automatically, by a domain-whitelist or by clicking the validator item.

You can and should up your own validator.nu-instance (at least on Linux and Mac OS X) - see [this](http://about.validator.nu/#src). You would then have a locally-running validator and can even check sites without an Internet connection by filling in `http://localhost:8888/` (the default address of the local validator instance) into the `Validator URL` of the addon.

To give credits: I have the information above from *[Validating HTML5 with validator.nu and the HTML5Validator Extension for Firefox](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201102/validating_html5_with_validatornu_and_the_html5validator_extension_for_firefox/)*.

Answer (score 4):

On the Web Developer add-on, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60, if you use "Tools" > "Display Page Validation" it will show a bar at the top validating the page source code.  This is done via the W3C validator, but without you having to navigate there.

It is a shame the HTML Validator has no plans as of yet to incorporate HTML5 until at least version 0.9.

Answer (score 0):

This says it will do it: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2318 and I found this also: http://html5.validator.nu/

Comment: The problem with the first is that it requires me to click the icon to validate. I want it to automatically validate every page I visit so that I realize immediately if my website doesn't validate, like HTML Validator does. The second is web-based, there is an "official" one at the W3C website too.

Answer (score -4):

You can validate HTML5 at the following site:

> http://validator.w3.org/

Make sure on the options that you select the HTML5 document type.