# Is there an offline HTML validator for Firefox working on OS X?

Tags: macos, firefox, html, firefox-extensions

Is there an offline HTML validator for Firefox 10+ working on Mac OS X?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/ does not work in your firefox?

Comment: I need an extension, addon

Comment: can't find that information in the question ... related question: http://superuser.com/questions/107228/is-there-a-html5-validator-plugin-for-firefox

Comment: it doesn't work well after all, this extension needed some service which validating html and this service can't reach my subdomain bcause of security reasons... so I still don't have a html validator :)

Comment: so you need one which operates 'offline'? you should specify that in your question.

Comment: please accept my applologies, I thought that everyone needs an offline validator

Comment: assume idiots on the other side of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Does ist have to be a Firefox extension? Because Mac OS X includes W3Cs validator in com.apple.pkg.BSD already.

```
% pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/tidy
volume: /
path: /usr/bin/tidy

pkgid: com.apple.pkg.BSD
pkg-version: 10.7.0.1.1.1309412550
install-time: 1312458669
uid: 0
gid: 0
mode: 755
```

Open a shell and type `man tidy` and you are good to go. Dave Raggett wrote [a nice introduction](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) for the tidy utility if you want to know more...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option: http://habilis.net/validator-sac/

Not a Firefox extension itself but you can use it with the Firefox Web Developer Extension.